# What is the name of the V/Y-shaped sign used when adding something (a letter, word, etc.) to a sentence?

Tags: reading, signage

*My father is police officer.*
For example, when editing my student's writing (which is handwritten), this is what I do:

```
           a
```

*My father is* Y *police officer.*
If anyone happens to know how to do this in a word processing software, I'd be even more grateful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Most word-processing software allows you to _track changes_ so that you can simply fix the errors and the student will be able to see your changes in the document when you send it back to them. There isn’t really a way to emulate handwritten proofreading in digital word processing.

Answer (score 3):

It's an inverted [**caret**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret#Proofreading_mark).

> The caret was originally and continues to be used in handwritten form as a proofreading mark to indicate where a punctuation mark, word, or phrase should be inserted into a document. The term comes from the Latin *caret*, "it lacks", from *carēre*, "to lack; to be separated from; to be free from". The caret symbol is written below the line of text for a line-level punctuation mark, such as a comma, or above the line as an inverted caret (cf. U+02C7 ˇ CARON) for a higher character, such as an apostrophe; the material to be inserted may be placed inside the caret, in the margin, or above the line.
>   [- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret#Proofreading_mark)

If you're using a word processor, it might be easier to insert a comment with the correction, rather than a traditional proofreader mark.